# How can I write a batch file to ping every 10 milliseconds?

Tags: batch-file, ping, milliseconds

I am trying to write a batch file to ping a server every 10 milliseconds.  I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/345220) which shows how to ping a server every n seconds, but it crashes if I try to use 0.01:

```
@ECHO OFF
set IPADDRESS=x.x.x.x
set INTERVAL=60
:PINGINTERVAL
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 >> filename.txt
timeout %INTERVAL%
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

I know 10 ms is crazy fast - this is a speed test.  The reason I am trying to ping a server every 10 ms, is because I am testing a local handoff of comms.  I start off pinging one server, but as I cross a physical threshold, I ping a different server.  I am trying to determine the duration of downtime during the handoff.

How can I use milliseconds instead of seconds?

Comment: The server won't even respond in 10 milliseconds. What are you trying to accomplish by flooding the server with `ping` requests?

Comment: I thought that might come up.  I'll add to question.

Comment: Batch files weren't designed to work with sub-second intervals, so you'll have to choose an alternative...

Comment: @FZs I was unaware, thank you.  Should I just write a regular .exe?

Comment: `/n` only tells `ping` how often to ping, not how fast. Maybe `/w` would be a better fit (it tells `ping` how long to wait for a response in milliseconds) but I doubt that's what you intend to do.

Comment: `PATHPING` has an option that may be useful. `-p period        Wait period milliseconds between pings.`